# Is it possible to make a fragment transaction in background? If not, then what alternative can I use?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am making an Android app which involves checking status after every 4 seconds and take some action according to it. So when I get status 'Cancelled' I need to make a fragment transaction. For checking every 4 seconds, I am making a get request using an async task, contained inside a timertask. Suppose the application is background, the async task is running every 4 secs and if I get 'Cancelled' while the app is still in background, I am getting the following error in making the fragment transaction. What is the correct way to do it?

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1527)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1545)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:654)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:621)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dride.android.dride.MapActivity$15.run(MapActivity.java:805)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-05 19:20:01.160 11822-11822/com.dride.android.dride E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I tried to do the transaction inside a handler, but still getting the same error.

EDIT
Code for fragment transaction

```
fm.beginTransaction()
                    .remove(f1)
                    .add(R.id.fm_options_list, optionsFragment, "Option List")
                    .commit();
```

Note the fragment f1 is the one, inside which all of this is happening. (The async task, checking every 4 secs and making transaction when received 'cancelled')

Comment: Can we see where you use the code to commit the transaction?

Comment: That is just terrible you shouldn't do it this way. Use an `IntentService` to perform the action periodically in the background and then just save the state somewhere.  However try to avoid doing the same thing over and over again in the background that is terrible for battery life. Besides your app could be killed at any moment when it is not visible so your solution is also not reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will change it.